# React Recharts tooltip not showing proper data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have two lines plotted on a recharts one is plotting everyday and the other is plotting once every quarter. The recharts tooltip only shows up for the pink line when it is directly hovered over the plotted point and says 0 when it is not over the directly plotted point. I want the tooltip to always show the data during that time. I tried adding in the "filterNull={false}" into the tooltip but it did not work. Any Ideas?

```
<Tooltip content={renderTooltipContentGeneric} filterNull={false} />
     



export const renderTooltipContentGeneric = o => {
 const { payload, label } = o
 const total = payload?.reduce((result, entry) => result + entry.value, 0)

 return (
   <div className="customized-tooltip-content-core">
     <div className="list">
       {payload?.map((entry, index) => (
         <div
           className="listItem"
           key={`item-${index}`}
           style={{
             color: entry.color,
             display: 'flex',
             flexDirection: 'row',
             gap: '4px',
           }}
         >
           <div style={{ color: 'var(--white)' }}>{`${moment(label).format(
             'lll'
           )}: `}</div>
           {`${numeral(entry.value).format('0.000 a')} `}
         </div>
       ))}
     </div>
   </div>
 )
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to show where recharts is called and all of its props etc